Why is my fetch endpoint method seemingly not finishing?
So in my code, I have this function handling the clicking of a button. However, it seems like there is some problem holding up the fetch() function, since the "1" at the end never gets printed.
const handleSubmitCommentButton = async () => {
    console.log("0");
    await fetch("http://localhost:3001/postComment", {
        // const { author, comment, idOfParentPost, level } = req.body;
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body:
            JSON.stringify({
                author: "bob",
                comment: "commentToPost",
                idOfParentComment: "dunno",
                level: 0
            })
    });
    console.log("1)");
};

Here is the API endpoint associated with it. It seems to finish running, since in my code the "7" at the end is correctly printed to the console.
app.post("/postComment", async (req, res) => {
    const { author, comment, idOfParentPost, level } = req.body;

    const now = new Date();
    console.log("6");

    // Format the date to include only month, day, year, and time (hh:mm)
    const formattedDate = now.toLocaleString('en-US', {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        hour12: true // or false for 24-hour format
    });


    const idOfParentComment = null;

    await db.collection("comments").insertOne({
        author, comment, idOfParentPost,
        level, idOfParentComment, createdAt: formattedDate
    });

    console.log("7");
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Comment posted successfully' });
});

What could possibly be the issue?
I've tried to run print statements throughout my code to see what was happening. It seems like the fetch function finishes being called, but the code stops running after that and doesn't print the "1" to the console like it should.

If you check the Network tab of DevTools, do you see a response being returned? If not, is there an error code?

Are you seeing the console.log calls on the server?

is it possible that the fetch throws an error? use try/catch to check

@JaromandaX If it were throwing an error they'd see that in the console instead of 1

@Barmar - I agree - but what other explanation could there be?

You have no error handling in your server-side code and Express v4 does not process rejected async route handlers.

@barmar Yes, I am seeing the console logs on the server. I've also tried using a try catch block on the server code, but it also detects no errors. I wonder if this is an infinite loop?

Actually, I just checked the networks tab in inspect element. It seems like the fetch request just stays on "pending" forever, and the comments I entered don't render. However, when I reload the page the comments I entered before will render.

I don't see how you could see the console.log("7") yet it doesn't send the response from the following res.status(200).json(...)
